# Why won't this bash command run when called by python?

Tags: bash, shell, python, quoting

The command

```
$ find ~/foo/ -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 | parallel -0 cat
```

uses [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to print all the `.txt` files under `~/foo/`.

I have a python script where I want to call this bash command:

```
import subprocess, sys

def runBashCommand(my_command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(my_command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output  = process.communicate()[0]
    return None

def makeCommand(my_path):
    return "find {} -type f -iname \"*.txt\" -print0 | parallel -0 cat".format(my_path)
```

Issuing

```
>>> makeCommand('~/foo/')
```

returns

```
'find ~/foo/ -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 | parallel -0 cat'
```

but issuing

```
>>> runBashCommand(makeCommand('~/foo/'))
```

yields the error

```
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

what's the problem with my script?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323859/python-how-to-call-bash-commands-with-pipe

Answer (score 11):

You're not actually running a `bash` command. What you're doing is running an executable directly and passing it arguments.

Try the following script to see what is happening:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "a", "b", "|", "rev"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate()
```

The output will be:

```
('a b | rev\n', None)
```

There's no redirection happening, the "|" is being passed in literally. I.e., it is as if you had typed `find ... \| parallel ...`. Thus the error.

There's two ways to fix it.

- The easy way: pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen`. That will run it through the shell, with all that entails. If you do that, you also need to pass in a string instead of an array:

  ```
  import subprocess
  p = subprocess.Popen("echo a b | rev", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  print p.communicate()

  # Result: ('b a\n', None)
  ```

  If you do this, *be very careful about argument substitution into your string*.
- The robust way: open two processes using Python and pipe them together.

  ```
  import subprocess
  # First command
  p1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "a", "b"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  # Second command's input linked to the first one's output
  p2 = subprocess.Popen(["rev"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  # Read from p2 to get the output
  print p2.communicate()

  # Result: ('b a\n', None)
  ```

  This is more robust and doesn't spawn an extra shell, but on the other hand it is more typing. If you do this, *note that **no** shell substitution happens*. In your case it doesn't look like you need it, but if you'd want to use, say, `~`, you'd have to get it through Python (e.g. `os.getenv("HOME")`).

Comment: Can you expand on *"be very careful about argument substitution into your string"*?  It seems that this applies to your second method but no example is given as for how it applies to the first.

Comment: @Wildcard: with `shell=True`, it passes the whole string into the shell. Let's say you wanted to get the output of `ls` for a given directory. `subprocess.Popen(["ls", dir], ...)` would always work. However, `subprocess.Popen("ls " + dir, ..., shell=True)` would fail if `dir` had spaces in it... let alone what would happen if `dir` got set to something like `";rm -rf /*"`. So that would be something to really pay attention to, especially if `dir` comes from user input. But if you don't use `shell=True`, this kind of thing can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `split()` your command string as it contains characters that need to be processed by the shell, eg `~` and `|`.  Use the version:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(my_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```